# Unexpected pointer change after deferenced pointer affectation

Tags: c, pointers

One of my pointer is being changed after I deference it and affect it a value. I don't understand why, especially since the code in that function is runned multiple times but work most of the time. Here is the code :

```
typedef struct          s_freeList
{
  int                   sSize;
  struct s_freeList     *next;
  struct s_freeList     *back;
  int                   *eSize;
}                       t_freeList;

void            *addNode(void *addr, size_t size)
{
  t_freeList    *freeList;

  // Working stuff
  freeList = (t_freeList *)addr;
  freeList->sSize = size * -1;
  freeList->next = ((t_freeList *)g_startAddr)->next;
  freeList->back = g_startAddr;
  ((t_freeList *)g_startAddr)->next->back = freeList;
  ((t_freeList *)g_startAddr)->next = freeList;

  // Not working stuff
  printf("addr = %p\nsize = %d\n", addr, (int)size);
  freeList->eSize = addr + size - 4;
  printf("freelist->esize = %p\n", freeList->eSize);
  *(freeList->eSize) = size * -1;
  printf("freelist->esize = %p\n\n", freeList->eSize);

  return (collapseNodes(addr));
}
```

Here is the output with the address :

```
addr = 0x1647020
size = 32
freelist->esize = 0x164703c
freelist->esize = 0xffffffe00164703c
```

Comment: not your main problem, but `sSize = size * -1;` causes out-of-range assignment. `size` is a `size_t`, so negating it generates a large positive number which you then assign to `int`. It would be better to write `sSize = -(int)size;` although you should also be detecting and handling the case `size > INT_MAX` which will make your program go haywire.

Comment: Thank you but I checked it with a printf and it seems to be working fine !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your `printf` output, you're running on a platform with 64-bit pointers. Each pointer has size and, importantly, *natural alignment* of 8 bytes, which gives the following layout of your structure (offsets are in decimal):

```
  00    sSize;
  04    <padding>
  08    *next;
  16    *back;
  24    *eSize;
  32    <total size>
```

You're setting `freeList->eSize = addr + size - 4`, which, with `size = 32`, just happens to overlap with the higher portion of `eSize` field itself.

If you're going to do the address arithmetic, try to use the compiler-provided introspection facilities such as `sizeof` and `offsetof` wherever possible. They may reduce the incidence of such errors and will make the code more readable and more portable.

(Or, better yet, avoid the address arithmetic at all).

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried the code, but here is what I think its happening. The following few lines assign values for the new node and insert it into the list:

```
// Working stuff
freeList = (t_freeList *)addr;
freeList->sSize = size * -1;
freeList->next = ((t_freeList *)g_startAddr)->next;
freeList->back = g_startAddr;
((t_freeList *)g_startAddr)->next->back = freeList;
((t_freeList *)g_startAddr)->next = freeList;
```

Clearly, `addr` is a pointer to the newly inserted node. Now this is the interesting thing:

```
freeList->eSize = addr + size - 4;
```

assuming that `size == sizeof(struct s_freeList)` then what you are basically doing is assigning `eSize` its own address + 4 bytes! I think this is because the `sizeof(int *)` happens to be 8 bytes and in memory your structure probably looks like this:

```
----------
|sSize   |    <-- addr
----------
|next    |
----------
|back;   |
----------
|eSize;  |    <-- addr + size - 4 probably because sizeof(int *) == 8 bytes.
----------
```

So when you do:

```
*(freeList->eSize) = size * -1;
```

you are modifying the value of `eSize` since it points to itself!

Edit: I just when over the code and output again and what atzz says is right, you are probably running a 64-bit machine, but the idea is still the same, `eSize` is overwriting itself...